# Generated rig controls dont control the bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

Iam not sure if something has changed, but when I create *human (meta-rig)* and use *Generate Rig* the controls does not move the bones. I think in previous version it was just as simple as that to create working rig. Do I missing something? [[image: rigify1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those bones are the bones of the Meta Rig. Once you generate they are not used anymore. There are other bones that are hidden in the control rig. Unhide layer 29,30,31 and you'll see them.

Comment: Ah ok, so after generating the rig, you can just delete your skeleton  and unhide the generated one and parent it to the geometry? Seems little bit confusing to me, but ok. Is there a way to edit the controls as some of them are small or hidden in geometry and when I enter the edit mode, just the bones are visible and the controls disappear.